# GWT form upload using BlobstoreService App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am using GWT and Google App Engine Java for my application. I have a profile screen where
user enters profile information like name, age and address, saves it and gets success or failure message. I developed this initial application using GWT-RPC and it worked fine. I had a new requirement where I have to store image of the user. I am using BlobstoreService to store images. This has created complications in the flow. I had to use FormPanel as it is the only way to do a FileUpload in GWT. The BlobStore service servlet expects a redirect on completion. As a result it cannot now return any status back to my GWT application once the profile is saved. Is there easy to store images using GWT along with other form fields and show  a status message back to user once the profile is saved.

Answer (score 3):

i struggled a lot with this problem until yesterday I figured out the solution with much help from [Ikai Lan's blog](http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/). Basicaly what I did is follow his steps but with a few modifications because doing it exactly how he did it did'nt work for me:

1. Create a form panel : set encoding multipart, method post.
2. Make a GWT Remote Service that just has one method:public String getUploadURL() or something like that and in the IMPL write this:

   ```
   BlobstoreService service = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
   return service.createUploadUrl("/XXX/YYY");
   ```
3. In XXX you must put your project path, for example mine is com.fer.pyn.PictureYourNews
4. In YYY you must put the servlet mapping name for a new servlet that we will have to create: I put XXX = BlobUploader, I created a BlobUploader extends HttpServlet and you have to update the web.xml.
5. Okey, so this is the weird part that I could'nt figure out, thing is that when we make a RPC call to getUploadURL() in the remote ervice from step 2 that returns a weird addres, like: '/_ah/img/eq871HJL_bYxhWQbTeYYoA' and that is the .fromAction you have to put in your form from step one. You need to update the form's action every time so i suggest the following:

   ```
   public void initBlobStoreSession()
   ```

   {
        imageService.getBlobStoreUploadURL(new AsyncCallback() 
       {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(String result) {
           uploadFormPanel.setAction(result);
           System.out.println("Upload Form Panel Action set");
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
           //oops
       }
   });
   ```

   }

   So when you submit your fromPanel, IT WILL UPLOAD THE BLOB and you dont have to do anything, the tricky part is how to get the blob:
6. What you need to do now is create the YYY servlet we where talking about in step 4.
7. In the post method, this is important:

   ```
   private BlobstoreService blobService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
   Map<String, BlobKey> blobMap = blobService.getUploadedBlobs(request);
   BlobKey blobKey = blobMap.get(UPLOAD_WIDJET_NAME);
   ```

UPLOAD_WIDJET_NAME is the .setName for the FileUpload widjet.

1. What you are doing there is getting a key for yout BLob so you can reference it later.
2. Our next step is showing the uploaded image back to the GWT layer:

   ```
   //In the same post method from step 7
   ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
   String imageURL = imagesService.getServingUrl(blobKey);
   response.sendRedirect("/XXX/YYY?imgURL="+imageURL);
   ```
3. Now in the get method:

   ```
   String imageUrl = request.getParameter("imgURL");
   response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
   response.getWriter().println(imageUrl);
   ```
4. We are done, now you just have to

uploadFormPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {

```
        @Override
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {

            uploadFormPanel.reset();
            initBlobStoreSession();
            String imageUrl = event.getResults();
            Image image = new Image();
            image.setUrl(imageUrl);
            //if you are using jetty, leave this on
                            //or else it wont work
                            //Don't use GWT.getModuleBaseURL(), it doesnt 
                            //work well in development mode
            imageUrl.replace("http://0.0.0.0:8888/", "");
            System.out.println(imageUrl);
            final PopupPanel imagePopup = new PopupPanel(true);
            imagePopup.setWidget(image);


            // Add some effects

            imagePopup.setAnimationEnabled(true); // animate opening the image

            imagePopup.setGlassEnabled(true); // darken everything under the image
            imagePopup.setAutoHideEnabled(true); // close image when the user clicks
            imagePopup.center(); // center the image


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

check out [upload4gwt](http://code.google.com/p/upload4gwt/) which address uploading in GWT on AppEngine.

(disclosure: I created upload4gwt; it's not mature yet, however may be useful)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As a workaround I'm using a redirection to a servlet that print a status message for the client to parse.
I'm passing the websafe string representation of the key to that result servlet.

That's a bit hackey, I'd like someone to come with a better answer, or explain why the blobstore servlet have to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, things get more complicated with uploads in GWT.

You can save the form data and image in separate RPCs, and either include a status message in the response to the image upload, or fire off a 3rd RPC when the form returns to get any status or metadata you need.